# why this app can't be scrolled in the android device?

Tags: android, flutter

for writing a pull up to refresh demo, I write this code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  void Function(void Function())? _setStateAdd;

  void Function(void Function()) get setStateAdd => _setStateAdd!;
  set setStateAdd(void Function(void Function()) setState) {
    _setStateAdd ??= setState;
  }

  List<int> list = [];
  final scrollController = ScrollController();
  int page = 1;
  bool isLoading = false;
  
  HomePage() {
    list = List.generate(40, (index) => index + 1);
    scrollController.addListener(() async {
      print("pixels: ${scrollController.position.pixels}");
      if (scrollController.position.pixels == scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        print("滑动到了最底部");
        await getmore();
      }
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        body: buildBody(context)
    );
  }

  Widget buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      controller: scrollController,
      child: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: refresh,
        child: StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) {
            setStateAdd = setState;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text(list[index].toString()),),
              shrinkWrap: true,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> refresh() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

    setStateAdd(() {
      list = List<int>.generate(40, (index) => index + 1);
    });
  }


  Future<void> getmore() async {
    if (!isLoading) {
      setStateAdd(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });

      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      setStateAdd(() {
        list.addAll(List.generate(5, (index) => index + 1));
        page += 1;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

and i found that I can't scroll it in the android device, but I can in the linux desktop, after asking other's help, I fix it with this code using `StatefulWidget`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return HomePageState();
  }
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int length = 30;
  late ScrollController controller;
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    controller = ScrollController()..addListener(() async {
      print("pixels is ${controller.position.pixels}");
      if (controller.position.pixels ==
          controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        print("滑动到了最底部");
        await getMore();
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: refresh,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text("${index + 1}"),
                ),

                controller: controller,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> refresh() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    setState(() {
      length = 30;
    });
  }

  Future<void> getMore() async {
    if (!isLoading) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });

      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      setState(() {
        length += 5;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand why this can work, what's wrong with my code ?

---

**update**

I found this code in StatelessWidget works well

```dart
 Widget buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: refresh,
            child: StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (context, setState) {
                setStateAdd = setState;
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: list.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text(list[index].toString()),),
                  controller: scrollController,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi buddy，What I understand is that Flutter is divided into StatelessWidget and StatefulWidget. StatelessWidget cannot create dynamic pages, only static pages can be loaded. The StatefulWidget does not have this issue when loading. Stateless and Stateful are the key

Comment: you should know that `StatefulWidget` can be used in `StatelessWidget`, that's why I use StatelessWidget with StatefulBuilder